# What is the best way to determine the XlSheetType of objects in the Excel.Sheets collection?

Tags: excel, vba

What is the best way to determine the `XlSheetType` of objects in the `Excel.Sheets` collection?

I'm uncertain, so I created the function below to do it.

This works, but is there a better way?

EDIT: I have added the first `Sub` with `For-Next` loop to show how the function is intended be used.

```
Public Sub GetSheetTypeTest()
    Dim xl          As Excel.Application
    Dim wb          As Excel.Workbook
    Dim shts        As Excel.Sheets
    Dim sht         As Object
    Set xl = Excel.Application
    Set wb = xl.ActiveWorkbook
    Set shts = wb.Sheets
    For Each sht In shts
        Debug.Print sht.Name, GetSheetType(sht)
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetSheetType(ByRef sheet As Object) As Excel.XlSheetType
    Dim typName As String
    typName = VBA.TypeName(sheet)
    Select Case typName
        Case "Worksheet"
            ' For worksheets, the Sheet.Type matches XlSheetType, so just
            ' pass it through as the result.
            GetSheetType = sheet.type
        Case "Chart"
            ' For charts, the Sheet.Type is the kind of chart, such as Bar,
            ' Line, Pie, etc. So here we need to explicitly pass the correct
            ' XlSheetType value as the result.
            GetSheetType = XlSheetType.xlChart
        Case "DialogSheet"
            ' For dialog sheets, they don't even have the Sheet.Type property,
            ' and so again the correct XlSheetType must be explicitly passed
            ' as the result.
            GetSheetType = XlSheetType.xlDialogSheet
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the function?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you really need - numeric value of `xlSheetType` or its name.
Let's analyse this code and you can convert it to function according to your needs:

```
Sub ListSheets()
    Dim sh As Object
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        Debug.Print sh.Name, TypeName(sh),
        On Error Resume Next
        Debug.Print sh.Type
        If Err Then Debug.Print XlSheetType.xlDialogSheet '-4116
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Comment: You should read the comments in my code. Your code is insufficient for this task, and indeed it would return incorrect results for `Excel.Chart` sheets. The `Chart.Type` property is the type of chart, not the type of sheet.

Comment: Your function is named `GetSheetType`. First you must check if your sheet is a chart, and if it is in the next step you can verify the chart type. The question was: `What is the best way to determine the XlSheetType of objects in the Excel.Sheets collection?`

Comment: And what if I want to iterate through the `Excel.Sheets` collection to determine the `xlSheetType` for each sheet in it? I am unconcerned with the type of Chart. I want to know the type of Sheet.

Comment: Well, that's what the procedure I've given you does. Specifies the types of sheets. And once you know the type of sheet, you can make further actions dependent on this type.

Comment: As per my previous comment, your code gives incorrect results for objects of type `Excel.Chart`. The code in my OP handles all five documented types of sheets in `Excel.Sheets`, without resorting to an error handler, and the results are accurate.

Comment: The `DialogSheet` does not have a `Type` property and that's why I used error checking as a substitute, while the `Chart` type sheet has a `Type` property and this property is read, but the program returns `Chart.xlChartType` instead of the `Sheet.Type` (-4109) as you expected. You can only blame the manufacturer. If your version works as expected, then stick with it.